# Cannot read data from file

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read values from CSV file which is present in package com.example.
But when i run code with the following syntax:

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("Dataset.csv"));
```

It says:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:Dataset.csv

I have also tried using:

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("/com/example/Dataset.csv"));
```

Still not working.
Any help would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: It's not a class - so it's not really in a package as such. Is it a file on the file system, or is it in a jar file? We don't really have enough information about where the file is in the context of how you're running the code.

Comment: `is present in package com.example` Use `getClass().getResource` or `getClass().getResourceAsStream` on the current class, passing the package and name of the resource (eg "/com/example/Dataset.csv").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the `FileDataModel` from `org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file` then it can't take an input stream and needs just a file.  The problem is you can't assume the file is available to you that easily (see [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file)).

It might be better to read the contents of the file and save it to a temp file, then pass that temp file to `FileDataModel`.

```
InputStream initStream = getClass().getClasLoader().getResourceAsStream("Dataset.csv");
//simplistic approach is to put all the contents of the file stream into memory at once
//  but it would be smarter to buffer and do it in chunks
byte[] buffer = new byte[initStream.available()];
initStream.read(buffer);

//now save the file contents in memory to a temporary file on the disk
//choose your own temporary location - this one is typical for linux
String tempFilePath = "/tmp/Dataset.csv";  
File tempFile = new File(tempFilePath);
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
outStream.write(buffer);

DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File(tempFilePath));
...
```

Comment: Hi Vic thanks so much. I was looking specifically for Mahout. Can you please let me know what should be the path for tempFilePath in Windows.

Comment: np. Essentially the temp location can be anything you want that your app will have read/write permissions to. But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352326/when-does-system-getpropertyjava-io-tmpdir-return-c-temp) explains default temp locations very well. So for windows it is usually based on environment variable **TEMP** or java property `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` - but this can vary depending on many things.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReadCVS {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReadCVS obj = new ReadCVS();
    obj.run();

  }

  public void run() {

    String csvFile = "file path of csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // Do stuff here

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> CSV file which is present in package com.example

You can use `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` to access the resource from within the package. For example

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/Dataset.csv");//uses absolute (package root) path
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
//read from BufferedReader
```

(note exception handling and file closing are omitted above for brevity)