# Where can I store program data? (OS, Java)

Tags: java, directory

I know that every OS has a specific directory, where a program can store data. For example in macOS there is a directory called /Applications.

Where can I store program data from a java program (multi-user) on Windows, Linux and macOS? Is there a System.property?

Comment: You mean common to the application, not specific to the user?

Comment: `/Applications` is where applications are stored, not where applications store their data.

Comment: please look into this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352444/3852345

Comment: oh yes, khelwood, my bad. dilly, your link is wrong, because I do not want to know the temp directory. I want to create a configuration file, which should be stored in a directory created by my program. And therefore I need to know the path where to create the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system property **[user.home](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)** is a property that you can use.

```java
Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));

if (Files.isDirectory(path) && Files.exists(path)) {
    Path myFolder = path.resolve("my_folder");

    if (Files.notExists(myFolder)) {
        Files.createDirectory(myFolder);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I guess that works. Many programs create their directories in my home dir. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, same here. It's a very commonly used directory. No problem!