# Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

created a spring application via start.spring.io and I try to run the application but an error occurs:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
> start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Temp directory 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP' does not exist   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> com.studentex.student.StudentApplication.main(StudentApplication.java:10)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5] Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp directory 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP' does
> not exist     at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]  at
> org.springframework.boot.system.ApplicationTemp.getTempDirectory(ApplicationTemp.java:125)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.system.ApplicationTemp.getPath(ApplicationTemp.java:96)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.system.ApplicationTemp.getDir(ApplicationTemp.java:89)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.SessionStoreDirectory.getValidDirectory(SessionStoreDirectory.java:46)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.AbstractServletWebServerFactory.getValidSessionStoreDir(AbstractServletWebServerFactory.java:288)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.AbstractServletWebServerFactory.getValidSessionStoreDir(AbstractServletWebServerFactory.java:284)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configurePersistSession(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:416)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configureSession(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:406)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configureContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:383)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:246)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:198)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]    ... 13 common frames omitted

my code is here:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StudentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudentApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on how you try to start application.
You can set **-Djava.io.tmpdir=your existing folder with read/write permissions** in Run/Debug configuration if you use some IDE or just add it at the end of "run script" if you use console.

Comment: You may also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352326/when-does-system-getpropertyjava-io-tmpdir-return-c-temp) to see why the temp folder is set to  `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA in the Run/Debug Configuration check "Include parent environment variables" or "Include system environment variables" in the Environment Variables window.